# How can I get OwinContext from SignalR Hub?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app that is written on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework using c#.

In this app, I am using [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) to create a WebSocket connection between my app and the user's browser.

In my SignalR hub, I want to be able to access the `OwinContext` object.

How can I access the `OwinContext` object from my hub?

This is what I tried

```
Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext();
```

However, this is giving me the following error

> No owin.Environment item was found in the context.

I added the `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />` to my Web.Config file.

This is how `Startup` class look like

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
using System;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TestProject.App_Start.Startup))]
namespace TestProject.App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            ConfigureAuth(app);

            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // need to add UserManager into owin, because this is used in cookie invalidation
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = Settings.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider(),
                CookieName = Settings.ApplicationCookieName,
                CookiePath = Settings.CookiePath,
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED** Case use explanation

In some case I need to update the user claims from inside the Hub. This requires to inform the Authentication Manager about the new claims. So I use the following method to update the ClaimsIdentity

```
private static void InformAuthManager(ClaimsIdentity identity, HttpContextBase context = null)
{
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    if (context != null)
    {
        authenticationManager = context.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
    else
    {
        authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }

    var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true };
    authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(claims, authProperties);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the OwinContext?

Comment: I want to be able to update the user claims from within the hub. Please check my updated question with case use explanation

Comment: If you add a constructor like `MyHub(IAuthenticationManager  am)`, which of these three happens; Exception requiring Constructorless hub constructor, `am` is null, `am` has a value?

Comment: @ErikPhilips after I added the constructor like you requested the Hub was never created. No errors/exceptions. The `OnConnected()` was never called. Its like the Hub class was never called. Maybe reflection is used and if there is no parameter-less construction no instance is created.

Comment: So the problem is that SignalR is a stateless, requestless, contextless framework, so trying to get the OwinContex is a pain.  SignalR has a [DI resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) and that's your best bet at solving this issue unless you want to start using a more advanced DI framework (i would highly recommend [Autofac as it's the easiest one I've used with signalR](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html)).

Comment: you can try using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubName>();`  Through this you can call a method of Hub in a controller. Its not exact what you want but you can try if it is helpful to you.